# Evaluating $f(n)$ using mod function and floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For $n =1,2,3,\dots,12$, we are given that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
n & f(n)\\ 
1 & 0\\ 
2 & 3\\ 
3 & 2\\ 
4 & 5\\ 
5 & 0\\ 
6 & 3\\ 
7 & 5\\ 
8 & 1\\ 
9 & 4\\ 
10 & 6\\ 
11 & 2\\ 
12 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

How to express $f(n)$ as $\mod(\left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{c} \right \rfloor,d)$, where $\left \lfloor \cdot \right \rfloor$ denotes the floor function, $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Please check your data.  $d$ is at least $7$ and probably is.  The jumps are always $2$ or $3$ , indicating $\frac ac$ is in this range, except $f(2)$ to $f(3)$, which would be $6$.  I don't think it is possible because of that.

Comment: To amplify the previous comment, if the values shown for $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ were actually the values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, and the missing value was $f(2) = 6,$ I think there might actually be a formula of the form requested.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $f$ implies that $f(n) \equiv \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{c} \right \rfloor \pmod d.$

From $f(5) - f(1) = 0$ we therefore have
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{5a+b}{c} \right\rfloor -
\left\lfloor \frac{a+b}{c} \right \rfloor \equiv 0 \pmod d,
$$
or in other words there is an integer $k$ such that
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{5a+b}{c} \right\rfloor -
\left\lfloor \frac{a+b}{c} \right \rfloor = k d.
$$

Note that in general, for any real number $x,$ we have
$x - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor \leq x.$
For any, $y,$ therefore, $-y \leq - \lfloor y\rfloor < 1 - y$
and $x - y - 1 < \lfloor x\rfloor - \lfloor y\rfloor < x - y + 1.$
Putting $x = \frac{5a+b}{c}$ and $y = \frac{a+b}{c},$ then
$$
\frac{5a+b}{c} - \frac{a+b}{c} - 1 < 
\left\lfloor \frac{5a+b}{c} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{a+b}{c} \right\rfloor
< \frac{5a+b}{c} - \frac{a+b}{c} + 1,
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\frac{4a+b}{c} - 1 < kd < \frac{4a+b}{c} + 1. \tag1
$$

Similarly, from $f(5) - f(9) + 4 = 0$ we know there is an integer $h$ such that
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{5a+b}{c} \right\rfloor -
\left\lfloor \frac{9a+b}{c} \right \rfloor + 4 = h d,
$$
and we also have
$$
\frac{5a+b}{c} - \frac{9a+b}{c} + 3 < 
\left\lfloor \frac{5a+b}{c} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{9a+b}{c} \right\rfloor
 + 4 < \frac{5a+b}{c} - \frac{9a+b}{c} + 5,
$$
which then simplifies to
$$
-\frac{4a+b}{c} + 3 < hd < -\frac{4a+b}{c} + 5. \tag2
$$

Combining the inequalities in $(1)$ and $(2),$
$$ 2 < (k + h)d < 6.$$

Assuming $d$ is positive, then $k + h > 0.$
But since $k$ and $h$ are integers, this implies $k + h \geq 1$
and therefore $d < 6.$
But $f(10) = 6$ requires that $d > 6.$
So we have a contradiction.
Likewise we get a contradiction if we let $d$ be negative.

I do not think it is possible to define a function $f$ with the requested properties.